# Zoho Deluge - JSON POST

Tags: json, zoho, zoho-deluge

I am trying to use a POST command in deluge to recall a document. When I make the call I get back a no file found (I have verified the id is correct).

The format should come out like this: POST [https://sign.zoho.com/api/v1/requests/[Request](https://sign.zoho.com/api/v1/requests/%5BRequest) ID]/recall
https://www.zoho.com/sign/api/#recall-document

What am I doing incorrect?

```
//Get Zoho Request ID
resp = Sign_ID.toLong();

//add recall command
data = resp + "/recall";

// JSON
response = invokeUrl
[
    url: "https://sign.zoho.com/api/v1/requests/"
    type: POST
    parameters: data.toString()
];

info "Attempting to recall waiver..." + response;
```

Verified Sign_ID is returning correct value
Verified correct API call
Verified error code

Comment: I'm not sure of what the solution is. So here are a few debugging suggestions to hopefully get more information about the problem.

Comment: Add detailed: true to the invokeUrl cmd. This will provide more information in response. Sometimes the additional information is helpful.

Comment: Try running the same query using curl on a terminal commandline. This can be useful because if it works in curl then the issue is specific to the deluge script. If it fails in curl then sometimes the error message is different from deluge and helps with debugging.

Comment: Here is the example from the Zoho documents:

Request Example:
curl https://sign.zoho.com/api/v1/requests/[Request ID]/recall -X POST -H "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken <Oauth Token>"

Answer (score 1):

Other than what [@ZohoCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14250642) have mentioned.
From the [documentation](https://www.zoho.com/sign/api/#recall-document), it seems what you have done is almost right.

```
// Get Zoho Request ID
resp = Sign_ID.toLong();

// use a variable for the URL of the request
urlRequest =  "https://sign.zoho.com/api/v1/requests/" + resp + "/recall";

// JSON
response = invokeUrl
[
    url: urlRequest
    type: POST
];

info "Attempting to recall waiver..." + response;
```